# Loading block in Twig with no refresh

Tags: codeigniter, twig

i am using CodeIgniter with Twig, i wonder how can i load only the content block
without refreshing the page. I've seen this topic has been discussed but with Sympony Framework which i'm not familiar with.

I want to load only the Block Content area without refresh, I've tried to load the controller with Ajax but it keeps loading the whole page - including the header, footer etc.

Thanks.

**Here is the base file -  base.twig :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{{ site_title }} | CRM</title>
    {% include 'templates/css.twig' %}
    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'templates/header.twig' %}
        {% include 'templates/side_bar.twig' %}
            <div class="content-wrapper">


                    <!-- Main content -->
                    <section class="content">

                            <div id="{{ site_title }}">
                                {% block content %}

                                {%  endblock %}
                            </div>
                    </section>

            </div>



    {% include 'notifications_modal.twig' %}
    </div>
    {% include 'templates/footer.twig' %}

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the controller - about.twig**

```
class About extends MY_Controller  {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index()
{

    $this->data['site_title'] = 'about';
    $this->twig->display('about',$this->data);

  }

 }
```

**And here is the view - about.twig**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>TO DO {{ site_title }}</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Place the content you need refreshed into seperate view, only render that view when calling the the ajax and adjust container accordingly on success

Comment: By 'seperate view' - you means a page that doesn't extends anything?

Comment: Indeed, that is correct

Comment: Yeah - it's the first thing i've done - but i run into a lot of other problems  , the content is changed - but the url not....

Comment: The `URL`? You can't change the `URL` with javascript without reloading the page